# Parallel processing in R : Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 7 nodes produced errors; first error: unused argument (MARGIN = base::quote(2))

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to do parallel computing using the apply family of functions with the following lines of code.
the objective is to fit each column of the silum_ matrix to my specification and when I check

```
dim((simul_[,1]))
```

I get "NULL" which causes the problem with the apply function.
The complete code is the following:

```
## Library
lib_vec = c("MSGARCH", "matrixStats", "parallel")
invisible(lapply(lib_vec, f_install_load_lib)) 

## seed
set.seed(1234)
```

MSGARCH model Specification from the MSGARCH package

```
MSGARCH_spec <- CreateSpec(variance.spec = list(model = c("sGARCH", "sGARCH")),
                            distribution.spec = list(distribution = c("norm",
                                                                      "norm")),
                            switch.spec = list(do.mix = FALSE, K = NULL),
                            constraint.spec = list(fixed = list(), 
                                                   regime.const = NULL),
                            prior = list(mean = list(), sd = list()))
```

MSGARCH fitting: the sp500_logrets are just log-returns.

```
MSgarch_fit <- FitML(data = sp500_logrets, spec = MSGARCH_spec)
```

Simulating MSGARCH Log_returns

```
nsim <- 100 # number of simulations
nahead <- 1000 # size of each simualtion
MS_simul <- simulate(MSgarch_fit, nsim = nsim, nahead = nahead, n.start = 500, 
                     nburn = 100)
simul_ <- MS_simul$draw # retrieving the simulated data
```

Parallel computing settings

```
n_cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(n_cores[1] - 1)
```

fitting each simulation by parallel computing with the apply functions

```
fitt_ <- parSapply(cl, X = simul_, MARGIN = 2, FUN = FitML, spec = MSGARCH_spec)

stopCluster(cl)
```

The error I get is :

```
7 nodes produced errors; first error: unused argument (MARGIN = base::quote(2))
```

I think that
I am quite lost and would very much appreciate any help :)

Comment: This is a warning, not necessarily an error. If you made multiple attempts, are you sure you ran each time `stopCluster`?

Comment: Yes I did run stopCluster. And after the warnings, there is an error message.

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite explicit:

```
7 nodes produced errors; first error: unused argument (MARGIN = base::quote(2))
```

There is no parameter `MARGIN` in `parSapply()` / `sapply()`.
You're maybe mistaking with `apply()`.

Comment: I used the parApply function this time so that I could use the margin parameter. I think my code is reproducible if you generate a dataset from a normal distribution for the sp500_logrets. I am thinking that the error it might also be the fitt_ that is not preallocated but I don't know how to do that. Please help –

Comment: You can't update the error you get everytime the previous one is solved. Please close this issue and open a new one. For your new error, you might want to search first as it might have already been answered.